# Load env variables into helm chart from ready made kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, kubernetes-helm

I am currently creating pods on AKS from a net core project. The problem is that I have a secret generated from appsettings.json that I created previously in the pipeline. During the deployment phase I load this secret inside a volume of the pod itself. What I want to achieve is to read the values from the Kubernetes secret and load them as env variables inside the helm chart. Any help is appreciated Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please see how you can [use secret as environmental variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables)

As a single variable

```
containers:
- name: mycontainer
  image: redis
  env:
    - name: SECRET_USERNAME
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mysecret
          key: username
```

Or the whole secret

```
containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
    envFrom:
    - secretRef:
        name: mysecret
```

Answer (score 0):

Your secrets should not be in your appsettings.json because they will end up in your source control repository.
Reading secrets from k8s into helm chart is something you should never attempt to do.

Ideally your secrets sit in a secure secret store (a vault) that either has an API that your k8s hosted app(s) can call into

Or (the vault) has an integration with k8s which mounts your secrets as a volume in your pods (the volume is an in-memory read-only storage).

This way your secrets are only kept in the vault which ensures the secrets are encrypted while at rest and in transit.